# Where can I find a service manual for the TECSUN PL-660 to replace the failed circuit board flex cable myself?

Tags: receiver, equipment-troubleshooting, repair, tecsun

Diagnosed three nonfunctional TECSUN PL-660 radios (one from eBay Anon-CO, and two from Amazon) where can I find a service manual to replace the failed circuit board flex cable board assembly part?
Demonstration video of failed circuit board flex cable board assembly part = youtu.be/4XbAnSX2FHk

Comment: the 2nd google result for "tecsun pl-660 service manual" has them.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: I looked and I found an operation manual with no technical information and a schematic.  I couldn't find a service manual.

Answer (score 2):

Try this link and check if it is what you are searching for:
https://elektrotanya.com/tecsum_pl-660_schematic.pdf/download.html

Note: Google Safe Browsing deems this site as 'No unsafe content found'.
https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search

More information on repairs:
TECSUN PL-600 – Electrostatic Discharge Repair
https://swling.com/blog/tag/tecsun-pl-600-repair/

Answer (score 0):

Your question presumes, or hopes, several things, all of which would have to be true for you to read a service manual and replace the part yourself:

- The manufacturer wrote a service manual in a language that you can read, or that could be easily translated (manual couldn't be just an image for easy translation to be available)
- The manufacturer released the service manual, or left a copy where someone could post it to the internet
- The manufacturer makes spare parts available for purchase

It's quite possible that the manufacturer has not done these things, either because they didn't want to spend the money to do them, or because they would rather have the business of servicing the radios to themselves.  In other words, you may be asking for something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try: https://elektrotanya.com/tecsum_pl-660_schematic.pdf/download.html I simply entereed "TECSUN PL-660 service manual" This was the first hit. There were many of them.